# Question about Referencing Strings in C#

Tags: c#, object, reference, arraylist

Quick question.

Take the following code sample:

```
ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
string testString = "";
testString = "test";
arrayList.Add(testString);
```

In that code sample, if I were to do the following:

```
arrayList[0] = "anotherTest";
```

Would testString be changed to anotherText or would it remain the same? Is it that object that is put in or a copy of it, another string?

Thanks,
Christian

Comment: Where is Jon Skeet when you need him?

Comment: I still contend immutability is the central concept here. IF strings WERE mutable, then the answer to this question would be the opposite (assuming 'Add' copied the reference not the value at the reference). We could have the same reference everywhere but the value at that reference would be changing with the `=` operator. Everyone assumes the OP understands that every string he has is equivalent to `new String("...")`. But if he did, he wouldn't be asking the question in the first place.

Comment: This is all great. Thanks so much for all of your answers, they were all good. I'm actually going to have to ask this question again for a different code sample, an instantiated class. Thanks once again.

Comment: As a sidenote: Unless you work in .net 1.x you should rarely need `ArrayList`. Use `List<T>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Before:*

[image: Before]

*After:*

[image: After]

- Only the value of arrayList[0] is changed to a reference to "anotherTest". The value of the testString variable remains unchanged.
- String is a reference type. This means both the testString variable and arrayList[0] each (independently) hold a reference to the objects "test" and "anotherTest", not the value itself.
- Changing testString or arrayList[0] from one string to another string does not modify the original string. Strings are immutable. Only the reference to the string object is changed.

Comment: +1!! Thanks for bringing some sanity to this thread in light of the other, inaccurate answers.

Comment: @Domenic, see my response in my answer to your comment.

Comment: this is not because the string is reference type, even for the int it will be the same

Comment: `string` being a reference type has a lot of bearing on the problem, actually. For value types the answer will still be the same, but for completely different reasons, involving copying of values. @dtb's explanation is solid.

Comment: Wish I could upvote you twice now that you have pretty pictures... sigh.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 objects here: "test" and "anotherTest".

Stage 1:

```
arrayList.Add(testString) //Adds the reference stored in testString 
                          //to the end of arrayList.
```

After the execution of this line, arrayList[0] also contains a reference to "test" (since at this stage, testString contains a reference to the object "test").

You can check this:

```
Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(testString, arrayList[0])); //outputs true
```

Stage 2:

```
arrayList[0] = "anotherTest"; //stores a reference to the object "anotherTest" in
                              //arrayList[0]
```

We have not changed testString at all. It still references "test". You can chech that the references stored in arrayList[0] and testString are different:

```
Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(testString, arrayList[0])); //outputs false
```

testString -> stores reference to "test"
arrayList[0] -> stores reference to "anotherTest"

Answer (score 2):

When you have completed the first code block

```
 ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList(); 
 string testString = "";
 testString = "test";
 arrayList.Add(testString);
```

you have two references one to the `arrayList` and one to the `testString`.

The first element in `arrayList` references the same object as `testString`, that is the string with the value `"test"`.

The arraylist does contain a reference to the `testString` object, but the arraylist item 0 and the `testString` variable both references the same object.

When you do the assignment

```
    `arrayList[0] = "anotherTest";`
```

you implicitly instantiates a new `string` object containing `"anotherTest"`. This object is stored in the array item with index null.

So after the second block arraylist item 0 references the new string object and `testString` continues to reference the original string.

Answer (score 1):

In your example you are updating the first index of the list it self, not the original string that was added to the list.

even if you are not using a string for example a `Bitmap` class or even an `int` struct:

```
int i = 14;

List<int> myList = new List<int>();
myList.Add(i);

myList[0] = 3;
```

this will not affect the original i and it will remain 14.

Another thing you should know that the string class -unlike other classes in general- is **immutable** so:

```
string s1 = "some text";
string s2 = s1;
s2 += " another text";
```

the s1 will stay remains unchanged.

A normal class will not be immutable, like:

```
class MyClass
{
    public string MyString;
}

MyClass class1 = new MyClass();
class1.MyString = "Some String";
MyClas class2 = class1;
class2.MyString = "Other String";
```

This will effect the class1 string as will so it is now "Other String", and that because the classes are referance types.

Comment: String immutability has nothing to do with this; it is easily possible to reassign the value of `testString` even though strings are immutable, and if the OP's question was about a type of mutable object (i.e. not strings), the answer would still be "no."

Comment: @Domenic: I am not finished my answer yet.

Comment: OK, so now you've changed your answer to give a misleading example with `int` (where the code path is completely different, as explained in my own answer), plus a completely-irrelevant sidenote on string immutability.

Comment: And in response to the newest attempt... of course if you change the properties of an object, references to that will reflect the updated properties! What the OP is doing, and what `s2 += " another text"` is doing, is making references point to entirely new objects. Remember that the `+=` is short for `s2 = s2 + " another text"` and this becomes entirely clear; you're just making `s2` point to `"some text another text"`.

Comment: @Domenic: My answer is good answer. that is it. first I explained that he is updating to the array instead of the string. Then Because of his question: `Referencing Strings in C#` I explain more about strings and immutable and reference types. Do you get it now?

Comment: Your very first sentence is the only part of it that answers the question, and even then it simply states the result, not answering why. The rest of it is misleading (for the `int` case, where it conflates the behavior of value types like `int` with that of reference types like `string` or `Bitmap`) and irrelevant (for the immutability stuff, which is clear if you replace `string s2 = s1; s2 += "another text";` with the equivalent lines `string s2 = s1; s2 = "some text another text";`).

Comment: Oh well if having your answer be liked is what's important, than you definitely win! I'll settle for being relevant and correct though :).

Answer (score 0):

In fact none of the three answers so far are very accurate.

The testString variable always holds a reference to "test" in the example.
It never changes.

What's more important is that ArrayList also is a container that contains references to objects. So when you assign "anotherTest" to the 0th element, you in fact make the 0th element reference a different string object. This doesn't change the value of testString.

Answer (score -1):

Well, you could always run the code to find out ;).

The answer is that `testString` would not be changed. @dtb's answer explains why. I'll approach a different aspect of the problem, regarding your "Is it that object that is put in or a copy of it, another string?" question.

Let's break down what's going in your code:

- `testString` contains a reference to `"test"`.
- Calling `arrayList.add(testString)` sets `arrayList[0]` to be a reference to `"test"`.
- Doing `arrayList[0] = "anotherTest"` sets `arrayList[0]` to be a reference to `"anotherTest"`.

So, as you can see, there is no copying going on, ever. Strings are not copied, or (as some other answers have put it) "passed by value".

---

If your question was about a **value type**, like a `struct` or even just `int`, then the answer would *still* be that `testInt` is not changed, but in *that* case the reason would be that copying has occurred: value types *are* "passed by value", and copies of them do get created when you use the `=` operator.

Comment: It'd be awesome if the downvoters could explain what part of my post was technically inaccurate, but I'm pretty sure the voting on this thread is just people defending hurt feelings by now given all the -1s floating around :)

Comment: Right, before the horizontal line I am talking about reference types (including `string`); after that I am talking about a _hypothetical situation_ in which value types were involved, to clarify that "copying" would occur _in that hypothetical situation_, even though it does not in the OP's situation. Was that not clear?

Comment: OK, sorry. So, just to be clear, you're saying immutability has nothing to do with it? Because I see much of what you're saying as synonymous with that definition... and that I agree with.

Comment: @Steve The central concept is not immutability, as you can see by the fact that the OP's question would have the same answer if we replaced `string` with `Bitmap` throughout. (`Bitmap` is just my example of a mutable reference type.)

Comment: no it wouldn't have been. If I have two references to a bitmap, and i change one of the values inside the bitmap - both references will point to the bitmap with the changed values. Vs. two references to the same string - where you can not change the second character of the string and have both references point to it. What's the difference between the "second character" and "all characters"? none.

Comment: @Steve: here is the OP's code with `string` relaced with `Bitmap`: `ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
Bitmap testBmp = new Bitmap("");
testBmp = new Bitmap("test");
arrayList.Add(testBmp);
arrayList[0] = new Bitmap("anotherTest");` Clearly `testBmp` did not change, even though `Bitmap` is not immutable!!

Comment: Not it's not - and that's because your rewritten version assumes immutability. You've gone out of your way to say "new" each time. This IS the confusion. It's only "clear" to you because you have an intuitive understanding of the concept we call immutability.

Comment: I don't assume immutability at all! How could I, given that I'm playing with mutable objects?! The OP uses three objects in his code: `""`, `"test"`, and `"anotherTest"`. Same as me. Remember that `"test"` is syntactic sugar for `new String("test")`. Our code is exactly the same, just with different constructors being called.

Comment: The point is really that the OP never mutates any objects, he just reassigns references to various places. Which is why whether the objects he's playing with are mutable or immutable just plain doesn't matter.

Comment: If you assume the string of characters is treated as a List<int>... then, you could also rewrite his question - and illustrate the confusion thusly: `List<int> myString = new List<int>({1,2,3,4,5}); ArrayList list = new ArrayList(); list.Add(myString); list[0].myString.Clear(); list[0].AddRange({6,7,8,9,0});`

Comment: Your assumption that he understands that these objects are immutable is highlighted by this line: `The OP uses three objects in his code: "", "test", and "anotherTest".`

Comment: That code is pretty much entirely unrelated to the OP's code. His code assigned references; yours mutates objects.

Comment: ROFL... `That code is pretty much entirely unrelated to the OP's code. His code assigned references; yours mutates objects.` YEAH! That's EXACTLY the confusion he has!!!

Comment: I don't understand; he's using the `=` sign, which never mutates objects, mutable or immutable, value or reference type. Why would you think it does?

Comment: @Steve let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1078/discussion-between-domenic-and-steve)

Comment: Get past your own understanding and look at it from the perspective of someone who *doesn't know that*.

Answer (score -2):

The short answer to your question is "no".

Why? **Because Strings are immutable.**

Here's why:

From Wikipedia:

> If an object is known to be immutable,
>   it can be copied simply by making a
>   copy of a reference to it instead of
>   copying the entire object.
>   - [Wikipedia.org](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object)

Let's step through an example:

```
var a = "Testing";
var b = a;
```

Here, you've already got a string ("Testing") sitting at some location in memory (let's say location 0x001. So, the actual value of "a" becomes 0x001 on the first line.

And we set b = a on the second line... so b also gets set to 0x001 (since we're copying *references*).

Now, suppose we do this:

```
a = "Again";
```

Here, we have another string ("Again") sitting at some different location in memory (let's say location 0x022).

We know strings are immutable... so what happens here? Well... that means we assign by reference. So, the value of "a" becomes 0x022.

What does this mean for "b"?

It means, any variables pointing to 0x001 ("Testing") will STILL point to 0x001... so, in this case, "b", remains UNCHANGED.

And only "a", which we updated by changing it's *reference* will point to 0x022.

Comment: String immutability has nothing to do with this, and strings are not passed by value.

Comment: @Domenic, It has SOMETHING to do with it, because the real question is about the reference behind the scenes. Rephrasing the question as: "If I have a variable which represents a reference to a string, and I assign a new string value to that variable, does the reference change, or does the value at the location of that reference change? Makes it clear that the question is, in fact, about mutability. If the value at that location COULD be mutated, then the other references to that location WOULD be updated.

Comment: The question is about "mutability" only in the sense that every reference is "mutable" because you can use the equals operator to "mutate" what it references. It has nothing to do with string (im)mutability.

Comment: @Domenic, No, that's not the definition of mutable. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object

Comment: Right, that's my whole point; if you're saying the question has something to do with (im)mutability, you're wrong, because the only "mutation" that occurs is that references are being reassigned ("mutated"). Thus all the "scare quotes" in my above comment...

Comment: To respond to your third update... "if an object is known to be immutable, it can be copied simply by making a copy of a reference to it..." Well, it's also true that _if an object is of reference type, the equals operator simply makes a copy of a reference to it_. It's the fact that `string` is a reference type that matters, not that `string` is immutable; the exact same argument applies to the very-mutable `Bitmap` type, for example. In fact, one can replace strings with bitmaps in your third update and the argument holds completely.

Comment: Don't know why, yet another downvote got cast. Even the accepted answer points out the the value of the strings isn't changing - that they are immutable objects - which is the confusion the OP is having an issue with... so whatever. Downvote, but no comment... great.